# how to retrieve rows which contains only number?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, teradata

I have a table tab1 with structure as-

```
+-----------+--------+
|columnName |datatype|
+-----------+--------+
|col1       |VARCHAR |
+-----------+--------+
|col2       |VARCHAR |
+-----------+--------+
|col3       |VARCHAR |
+-----------+--------+
|col4       |VARCHAR |
+-----------+--------+
|col5       |VARCHAR |
+-----------+--------+
```

and sample data as

```
+----+-------+----+----+----+
|col1|col2   |col3|col4|col5|
+----+-------+----+----+----+
|11  |aaaaaaa|aaaa|aaaa|1111|
+----+-------+----+----+----+
|22  |bbbbbbb|bbbb|bbbb|2a2s|
+----+-------+----+----+----+
|33  |ccccccc|cccc|cccc|a312|
+----+-------+----+----+----+
|44  |ddddddd|dddd|dddd|4444|
+----+-------+----+----+----+
```

Now i want to retrieve only those rows having col5 with only numbers ( like 1st and 4th row). How to write the query in oracle and teradata?

Comment: Is it mysql or oracle?

Comment: My assumption is that since he noted that it was a specific version of Oracle that is correct. He may be doing the classic mysql = sql that I wrote.

Comment: @juergen in oracle and teradata

Comment: @Zane : It is actually in oracle and teradata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the column is 4 characters (as in the sample data), the only code that I can think of that works in both databases is:

```
select t.*
from tab1 t
where substr(t.col5, 1, 1) between '0' and '9' and
      substr(t.col5, 2, 1) between '0' and '9' and
      substr(t.col5, 3, 1) between '0' and '9' and
      substr(t.col5, 4, 1) between '0' and '9';
```

This is a bit brute force.  But when getting SQL that works in multiple databases, you often have to limit the functionality that you use.

EDIT:

The function for string length is the same in Oracle and Teradata.  So, for shorter strings you can do:

```
select t.*
from tab1 t
where substr(t.col5, 1, 1) between '0' and '9' and
      (length(t.col5) < 2 or substr(t.col5, 2, 1) between '0' and '9') and
      (length(t.col5) < 3 or substr(t.col5, 3, 1) between '0' and '9') and
      (length(t.col5) < 4 or substr(t.col5, 4, 1) between '0' and '9');
```

Comment: could you please provide me the query for only teradata?

Comment: what if i combine and codition like <code> select t.*
from tab1 t
where substr(t.col5, 1, 4) between '0000' and '9999' ; <code> <br> will it fetch any unwanted data? and i guess it should 9 than 1 in your query.. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @netuser . . . The '1' should be '9's (fixed).  If you search for `between '0000' and '9999'`, then you will get `'1abcd'` as a match.

Comment: i forgot mention like col5 can also contain values like '0', '12' ,'432' .. so on.. how can we fetch only those rows with col5 has only 4 digit number?

Answer (score 1):

If there's the oTranslate UDF installed in Teradata you might try an old trick, remove all digits and check if the resulting string is empty:

```
where char_length(oTranslate(col5, '0123456789', '') = 0
```

Oracle will be similar, probably:

```
where length(Translate(col5, '.0123456789', '.') = 0
```

Comment: Why can't the Oracle version use the same set of arguments? I.e. why did you add a `'.'` to both the *from_string* and the *to_string*?

Comment: Oracle treats an empty string '' like a NULL, this is a known "feature", to avoid an empty string as 3rd parameter you simply replace a character with itself. You could use the same in Teradata, but it's not needed...

Comment: Ah yes, I did already know that but not being an Oracle person I still forget about it sometimes. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function

isinteger(colN)

```
replace FUNCTION "temp_DB".isinteger(X VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS BYTEINT
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COLLATION INVOKER
INLINE TYPE 1
RETURN
CASE
    WHEN
        CHARACTERS(X) > 18 -- first elimination biggers from bigint
    THEN 0
    WHEN
        TRANSLATE_CHK(X USING unicode_to_latin) <> 0
    THEN 0
    WHEN   
        UPPER(X)(CASESPECIFIC) <> LOWER(X)(CASESPECIFIC) -- for letter control
    THEN 0
    WHEN
        CHAR2HEXINT(X) LIKE ANY -- for other controls
        (
        '%A%','%B%','%C%','%D%','%E%','%F%', -- if hexadecimal codes have a letter that can't be a integer
        '%0020%','%0021%','%0022%','%0023%','%0024%','%0025% ','%0026%','%0027%','%0028%','%0029%','%0040%','%0060% ' -- and other characters
        )
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1
END
```